# Nuget restore error: This folder contains more than one solution file

Tags: c#, nuget, build-process, nuget-package-restore

I have this structure of solutions and projects:

```
projects
|--.nuget
|  |--packages.config
|
|--projFolderA
|  |--projectA.csproj  
|  
|--projFolderB
|  |--projectB.csproj  
|
|--projFolderC
|  |--projectC.csproj  
|    
|--solutionAB.sln
|--solutionBC.sln
|--solutionCA.sln
```

Each solution is configured to use some libraries using nuget. Now, when I run:`nuget restore`, I got this error: `This folder contains more than one solution file.` But if I open each solution in VS2013 then it's fine.

This is the nuget settings in each of my *.sln file:

```
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = ".nuget", ".nuget", "{334B5D1D-8694-472B-8170-3D36A395DCEF}"
    ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        .nuget\packages.config = .nuget\packages.config
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

What did I do wrong ? How can I run `nuget restore` from console in this case ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try `nuget restore solutionABC.sln`

See https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference

See bolded section below as to why you get the error.

> Restore Command Notes
>
> The restore command is executed in the following steps:
>
> Determine the operation mode of the restore command.
>
> If *packages.config file* is specified, nuget restores packages listed in the packages.config file.
>
> If *solution* is specified, nuget restores packages for the solution's projects. In this case, nuget needs to locate the solution file.
>
> If *solution* is a file, that file is used as the solution file.
>
> If *solution* is a directory, then nuget searches for a *.sln file in that directory. If exactly one file is found, that file is used as the solution file. Otherwise, nuget displays an error message and exits.
>
> If no argument is provided,
>   nuget first looks for solution files in the current directory. **If there is just one solution file, nuget will restore packages for that solution. If there are multiple solution files, an error message is displayed and nuget exits.**
>
> If there are no solution files, nuget then searches for the packages.config file in the current directory. If the file exists, nuget will restore packages listed in the packages.config file.
>
> If there are no solution files and no packages.config file in the current directory, an error message is displayed and nuget exits.
>
> If the operation mode is restoring for a solution, then -SolutionDirectory option is not applicable. In this case, nuget displays an error message and exits.

Comment: Thanks. Interestingly at the last line of "nuget.exe", it said : `For more information, visit http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference`. Damn lazy me